# Please enable TCP/IP protocol. Unity3D

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols, unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect to MS SQL database.
Here is my code:

```
void Start ()
    {
        string connectionString =
            "Server=MyServer;" +
            "Database=Data;" +
            "User ID=User;" +
            "Password=psd;" +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI";
               Debug.Log("conn string");

    List<int> result = new List<int>();

        string sql = "SELECT RecordCount FROM MainDB";
        IDbConnection dbcon;
        dbcon = new SqlConnection (connectionString);
        dbcon.Open ();
        IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand ();
              dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
        IDataReader rdr = dbcmd.ExecuteReader ();

        while (rdr.Read()) {
            result.Add ((int)rdr.GetValue(0));
        }

        Debug.Log("get"); 
        // clean up
        rdr.Close ();
        rdr = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose ();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbcon.Close ();
    dbcon = null;
    }
```

I copyed most of code from mono-project. I allowed UDP port 1434 and mono.exe in my firewall rules. And Iam still getting message:

> NotImplementedException: Mono does not support names pipes or shared
>   memory for connecting to SQL Server. Please enable the TCP/IP
>   protocol.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection+SqlMonitorSocket.DiscoverTcpPort
>   (Int32 timeoutSeconds)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.DiscoverTcpPortViaSqlMonitor
>   (System.String ServerName, System.String InstanceName)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ParseDataSource (System.String
>   theDataSource, System.Int32& thePort, System.String& theServerName)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () ConnectToDB.Start () (at
>   Assets/ConnectToDB.cs:33)

What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Unity issue. This is an issue between Mono  and MS SQL. You should re-tag/re-ask your question so that MS SQL experts see it.

Comment: "I allowed **UDP** port 1434 and mono.exe in my firewall rules. And Iam still getting message:" have you opened it for TCP/IP?

Answer (score 1):

You can popular third-party solutions such as [SmartFox Server](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/) or [Photon](http://www.exitgames.com/) if you need help establishing TCP/IP sockets.